# creating plot side effects with do or summarise in dplyr

Tags: r, rstudio, dplyr

I'm using `do()` to fit a model to grouped data, and then I want to plot the fit for each group. In `plyr`, I guess I would use `d_ply()`. In `dplyr`, I'm trying either `do()` or `summarise()` using a function that makes the plot as a side effect.

I'm getting different results depending on whether I use `do()` or `summarise()`, and I'm not sure why. Specifically it seems like `summarise()` isn't operating on each row correctly.

Here's my example:

```
require(nycflights13)
require(mgcv) 
# fit a gam to the flights grouped by dest (from ?do)
by_dest <- flights %>% group_by(dest) %>% filter(n() > 100)
models = by_dest %>% do(smooth = gam(arr_delay ~ s(dep_time) + month, data = .))
# print the first 4 rows, the dest is ABQ, ACK, ALB, ATL
models %>% slice(1:4) 

# make a function to plot the models, titled by dest
plot.w.title = function(title, gam.model){
  plot.gam(gam.model, main=title)
  return(1) 
}

# This code makes plots with the wrong titles, for example ATL is listed twice:
models %>% 
  slice(1:4) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  summarise(useless.column = plot.w.title(dest, smooth)) # for plot side effect

# this code gives me the correct titles...why the difference?
models %>% 
  slice(1:4) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  do(useless.column = plot.w.title(.$dest, .$smooth))
```

Comment: When i run the summarise() code i don't see ATL twice. I see ABQ, ACK, ALB, and ATL. How are you viewing these plots?

Comment: This might be an `RStudio` problem. When I use the `x11` or graphics device, things work as expected, but in the `RStudio` graphics device I have the same problem.

Comment: It was on the Rstudio graphics device...I didn't even think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The summarise() method will work if you modify the function by applying unique() to the title:

```
plot.w.title = function(title, gam.model){
  plot.gam(gam.model, main=unique(title))
  return(1) 
}
```

Comment: that works -- thanks! Just wondering though -- how did you think to try unique? Is there something about how rowwise or summarize works that I should know?

Comment: My thinking was that it was assuming you were supplying the title argument as a vector even though you had specified rowwise. That's why I tried unique to convert it to a single value. Given that others have stated that this is a graphics device issue, the fact that unique worked was just pure luck :p